# "Ionic v4"-App build with Phonegap shows white screen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, ionic4

I've written an App with Ionic v4. With Ionic I can build the APK. For Phonegap I created a `.zip` file out of the `www` folder including adjusted `config.xml` and `resources` folder.
On [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com) it builds and I can download it via QR-Code. After installing the app it briefly shows the title of that application, but afterwards there's just a white screen.
Already tested a starter porject - `ionic start [name] tabs` - in version 3 and 4. Version 3 was working; Version 4 same issue.
Is there a way to make ionic v4 working or do i have to switch back to v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your routing is not setup correctly. Routing was one of the big changes in ionic 4. Try to find a migration guide to fix the changes in your code of the ionic framework. Try this guide [Klik here](https://moduscreate.com/blog/upgrading-an-ionic-3-application-to-ionic-4/)

Comment: I have created the blank ionic 4 App and build using the ionic cordova build android --prod and zip the www and config.xml file and upload in to phonegap build site. we can generate the build successfully. but App is closed automatically. can you guys advice please?

Comment: @VenkaTeshuser5397700, The info that you gave me is not sufficient enough to give you a direction. But first check your logs and stack-traces. This will give you a direction to debug your issue.

Comment: GuacaMollee We are using phonegap site for app generation